# How to create distorted / wavy checked boxes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, path, patterns, distort

I'm trying to replicate the chequered boxes on the following image (sorry for really low-res)

[image]

Notice how the squares distort / warp with the shape of the path.

I can create the chequered boxes easily as a pattern in Illustrator... I then pasted them into Photoshop and tried the Warp tool (but this really didn't go very well).

Perhaps it is a better idea to create some form of Brush in Illustrator instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Pattern Brush could certainly do it.  After applying it to a path, you could then use the Width Tool to change the thickness of the brush stroke.

Example

[image]